# Magento 2: Year wise Product Display Layout Change on Category Page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom, filter, category-products

I have attribute as Year for Product. Would like to display product's on basis of Year.

**I already created Year Attribute  & assign it for Sorting as well.**

Attached image for reference.

[image]

How to achieve this? When it clicks on Year or View More it will display all products relates to that Year

Issue here is Layout for Only Year i need below kind of layout or result.
Per row year wise only 4 products with View More Button. Year Link also. Both links to Another Listing where it displays all Product Listing with paging of that particular Year.

If for year we don't have data, then it skips that year.

So it's Horizontal kind of Sorting for Year ONLY. Apart for "Name" it wil be Vertical as Magento Default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create product attribute and set it's frontend property

[image]

if you set Yes to sorting in product list your attribute shows in frontend sort by option.

Comment: Ronak, it is good idea and logic

Comment: Hi @RonakChauhan. That is basic which i already done. If you look into image. It's Not Vertical Sorting. You have to display data Horizontally & Max 4 Per Year. Then "View More" Button. On Year title we also have link to show
that particular Year's Data.

Answer (score -1):

Here i have set year attribute and also sort using year and getting perfect result, if you want to test you can print that year along with products.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Ronak Please read question in detail. U will get idea what i'm trying to say